# How would I code a userscript to receive a desktop notification from a website?

Tags: web, notifications, greasemonkey, userscripts

I need to write a userscript that detects when an element on a website changes (in this case, it's when somebody receives a popup notification on the screen in the website), and from there sends a desktop notification alerting the person that they have a notification from that website.

I hope this was clear enough, I have very little coding experience so please make this as understandable as possible, I just need to know what to even start out with or do in the first place, thank you

Answer (score 1):

> I need to write a userscript that detects when an element on a website changes

You can use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

> sends a desktop notification alerting the person that they have a notification from that website

You can use the notification API in script managers.

```
GreaseMonkey:       GM.notification 
ViolentMonkey:      GM.notification/GM_notification
TamperMonkey:       GM_notification
FireMonkey:         GM.notification/GM_notification
```